# Unexpected behavior with eq operator in a perl while loop. while loop does not stop

Tags: perl

While loop below does not stop after scalar `$quit` clearly does not equal 'j'.
Why won't it stop?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
my $quit = 'j';

while ($quit eq 'j') {

    print "Enter whatever value you want and I bet I still continue.\n";
    chomp (my $quit = <STDIN>);
    print "quit equals: $quit\n";

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the loop you are creating a new `$quit` variable with the `my` keyword:

```
chomp (my $quit = <STDIN>);
```

You actually want to assign to the existing variable:

```
chomp($quit = <STDIN>);
```

Note that a Perl linting program such as [Perl::Critic](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Critic/bin/perlcritic) would have alerted you to this problem:

> Reused variable name in lexical scope: $quit at line 9, column 12.  Invent unique variable names.  (Severity: 3)

Answer (score 4):

You redefine `$quit` in the Loop : `chomp (my $quit = <STDIN>);` remove `my` in this line

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $quit = 'j';

while ($quit eq 'j') {

    print "Enter whatever value you want and I bet I still continue.\n";
    chomp ($quit = <STDIN>);
    print "quit equals: $quit\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you define a new variable $quit inside your while loop. 
This is what you want:

```
chomp ($quit = <STDIN>);
```

So, without 'my'.